# Add a button to the top right of action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-button

Is there a way I can add a button to the top right of my `ActionBar`, like where the default settings `Button` is? I removed the settings `Button` but I'd like to add a custom `Button` in it's place.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can add a button by editing/create the menu xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/you_resource_here"
        android:title="Text to be seen by user"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="0"/>

</menu>
```

Then in your activity, if you created a new file your need to edit `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and you can edit what the actions do in the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_name) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this in a bit and return

Comment: Sorry, I know this is late, but for some reason nothing happens when I click on the button.  Is there some other code I need to add?

Comment: If you're seeing the icon appear in the ActionBar, then clicking it should work with what's written above. Try adding a Toast/log line to the first line of onOptionsItemSelected, the issue could be somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

This might be easier, however I use a toolbar instead:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_name:
            //your code
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```